# Why the Ruby each iterator goes first in the execution?

Tags: ruby, iteration, each, puts

I've came across a weird thing doing simple tasks in Ruby. I just want to iterate the alphabet with the each method but the iteration goes first in the execution:

```
alfawit = ("a".."z")
puts "That's an alphabet: \n\n #{ alfawit.each { |litera| puts litera } } "
```

and this code results in this: (abbreviated)

```
a
b
c
⋮
x
y
z
That's an alphabet: 

 a..z
```

Any ideas why it works like this or what supposedly I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: Listing the alphabet after the "That's an alphabet" like it is done properly by Ursus. I had thought that I am able to nest the iteration the way I did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `each` call is interpolated in your string literal that's executed before the fixed string. Also, `each` returns an `Enumerable`, in fact you print even that. Try this one

```
alfawit = ("a".."z")
puts "That's an alphabet: \n\n"
alfawit.each { |litera| puts litera }
```

or

```
puts "That's an alphabet: \n\n"
("a".."z").each { |litera| puts litera }
```

you can use interpolation if you want but in this way

```
alfawit = ("a".."z")
puts "That's an alphabet: \n\n#{alfawit.to_a.join("\n")}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to understand that for a few days but that was so simple.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily see what's going on if you extract the interpolation part into a variable:

```
alfawit = ("a".."z")
foo = alfawit.each { |litera| puts litera }
puts "That's an alphabet: \n\n #{ foo } "
```

The second line is causing the trouble: [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-each) invokes the block for each element of the range and then returns the receiver, so that `foo` becomes `alfawit`.

Here's another way to get the desired result:

```
alfawit = "a".."z"
puts "That's an alphabet:", alfawit.to_a
```

`puts` outputs each argument on a new line, but for array arguments, it outputs each *element* on a new line. Result:

```
That's an alphabet:
a
b
c
⋮
x
y
z
```

Likewise, you can turn the range into an [argument list](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) via `*`:

```
alfawit = "a".."z"
puts "That's an alphabet:", *alfawit
```

That's equivalent to:

```
puts "That's an alphabet:", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
```